# SVN error when commiting changes

Tags: eclipse, svn

I'm trying to commit some changes using subeclipse and i'm having this problem:

[image]

On the previous branch we were not having this problem. How can i solve this?

Comment: Seems you have a commit hook complaining about something. Most likely about your commit message format.

Comment: @mp911de I've figured out the message format. But now it's giving me this message: The CR xxx is not ON DEVELOPMENT.

I guess it's time to talk with our configuration managers.

Answer (score -1):

Disable the respective hook on your SVN server. [Implementing Repository Hooks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks)

Comment: How would that solve the actual problem? The hook is there for a reason.